# locate & updatedb - files not found

Tags: command-line, search

I ran

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

then

```
locate Radium3
```

but it returns nothing!

but

```
$ ls ~/Library/Containers/com.catpigstudios.Radium3/
Container.plist Data
```

So why doesn't `locate` see all the files?

Am I using this command correctly on OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

And look config:

/etc/locate.rc           the configuration file

**Edited:**

Post here output:

```
echo $LOCATE_CONFIG
```

And:

```
cat /etc/locate.rc
```

And:

```
echo $0
```

**Update:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/locate.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/locate

The locate program searches a database for all pathnames which match the specified pattern.  The data-base database
     base is recomputed periodically (usually weekly or daily), and **contains the pathnames of all files
     which are publicly accessible**.

Try **mdfind** instead **locate**

**Updated2:**

**mdfind -name text which is more accurate. Just mdfind text gives you files that contain text as well. –  David Krmpotic**

```
mdfind -name text
```

Comment: I uncommented `#SEARCHPATHS="/"` in config, it didn't help. `-v` option doesn't seem to produce any additional output :/

Comment: Give additional info for me plz. In answer "Edited" section.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8998774

Comment: BTW, 'locate'  finding something else? Did you have /var/db/locate.database?

Comment: $ ls -la /var/db/locate.database
-r--r--r--  1 nobody  wheel  19463861 Apr  6 20:08 /var/db/locate.database
$ locate david.jpg
/Users/david/temp/david.jpg

Comment: Try **mdfind** instead **locate**

Comment: you should update your answer to `mdfind -name text` which is more accurate. Just `mdfind text` gives you files that *contain* text as well.

Comment: mdfind doesn't search hidden files (those that start with a `.`) which makes it less useful for general searching.

Answer (score 3):

Permissions may be the culprit as locate apparently cannot read files that are not world readable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887889/2870587) by [Plundra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212846/plundra) for more explanation.

The [findutils](http://braumeister.org/formula/findutils) package from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) does enable `gupdatedb` and `glocate` commands that seem to overcome some of the limitations of the builtin utilities.

Comment: Thank you! but now that I know about `mdutil` does it make sense to check out this? One use case I can think of is that I can trigger rescan manually with `gupdatedb` - with Spotlight not so easy or it would take longer (it also indexes files contents). Are there other advantages?

Comment: Reindexing with mdutil/spotlight can take awhile for sure. `updatedb` is quicker for that. `glocate` seems to have no problem indexing system files, while I find `mdfind` ignores ~/Library and other system files. I definitely find I get more hits with `glocate` over `mdfind` in most circumstances. YMMV.

Comment: ok, I'm testing this now. I think I found some problem... fist I ran `sudo gupdatedb`, then saved `glocate Radium` output. Then I ran `gupdatedb` and it said: `/.Trashes: Permission denied`, the same for some other folders. I compared the output for both and it was the same! Strange...

Comment: From what you're saying, you first ran `sudo gupdatedb` (running it as root), then you followed up later by running `gupdatedb` as a normal user which would not have access to the files that the root user would have access to, meaning you'd get permission denied errors. If you want a complete database of filenames for your whole system, keep running it as root. This does expose your files to other users on the system who may use the `glocate` command. But if you are the only user, that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search the same database that Spotlight uses, you can use the `mdfind` command as an alternative (although not an exact replacement) for `locate`:

```
mdfind Radius3
```